# Конвертирование строчки с hex в нормальный вид на php

Tags: php, hex

Доброго времени суток знатоки. Пробовал сам, спрашивал у знакомого, не можем разобраться. Есть строчка

```
$string = "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2E\x63\x6F\x2F\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x2F\x34\x4E\x6E\x4D\x64\x42\x37\x57\x6A\x53\x34";
```

Мне необходимо сконвертировать ее.
Использовал разные функции которые смог придумать.

```
  function convertHexToStr($hex) {
  if (!ctype_xdigit(str_replace("\x", "", $hex))) {
    return $hex;
  }

  for($i= 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
    $sub_str = substr($hex, $i, 2);
    $dec_sym = hexdec($sub_str);

    if($dec_sym != 0) $str .= chr($dec_sym);
  }

  return $str;
}
```

и такую

```
function convertHexToStr($hex){
  for($i= 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
    $dec_sym = hexdec(substr($hex, $i, 2));
    if($dec_sym != 0) $str .= chr($dec_sym);
  }
  return $str;
}
```

И прочие. Срабатывает визуально нормально, получаю раскодированную строчку

> https://openload.co/embed/4NnMdB7WjS4

Но. Толи в кодировке дело, толи в чем, ссылка получается не рабочей, при том что она вполне рабочая. Ниже скриншоты
https://prnt.sc/jdakhi
https://prnt.sc/jdakk5
Может есть другие решения?

Comment: Приведённая строка уже декодирована. [Пруф](https://3v4l.org/ZnKfe). Вероятно имелось в виду то же самое в апострофах? Или нужно слеши экранировать.

Comment: Ну и вопрос, с чего вы взяли, что "ссылка получается нерабочей"? Как проверяете?

Comment: https://123moviesget.com/iframe.php?url=4NnMdB7WjS4 вот по ссылке видно что фрейм внутри нее не рабочий. посмотрите исходный код страницы. найдете ссылку. если ее скопировать и вставить в браузер, то фрейм рабочий.

Comment: Таки у вас там undefined, а не код

Comment: Смотрите что за жесть происходит на 64 строке. Там скрипт повторно загружает фрейм теряя код.

Comment: не понял) http://prntscr.com/jdsjik

Comment: https://imgur.com/o0aebBZl.png

Comment: фрейм загружается, но ломает сам себя

Comment: все потому что конвертирование с hex криво происходит. тут и суть вопроса, может кто подкинуть функцию для преобразования строчки с hex в обычную, текстовую

Comment: Вы кликали пруф в первом комментарии?

Comment: нажимал. тут я задумался. может на стороне сайта проблемы, сейчас перепроверю